# trial period in Checkout session in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to create trial period to be used with stripe checkout session:

```
session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            customer=customer.stripe_id,
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=[{
                'price': "price_1HjynjHdAhQwSUAK",
                'quantity': 1,
                'tax_rates': ["txr_1Hkntg4yXtzmX", ],

            },
            mode='payment',
            allow_promotion_codes=True,
            success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('thanks')) + '?session_id=CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('index_payment')),
        )
```

in the [tripe.Subscription.create](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials) looks like we just need to add trial_end=1605387163, but it doesnt work in checkout session. I cant seem to find the way to do it even though I am pretty sure it is doable as displayed in this [demo](https://checkout.stripe.dev/configure):
[image]

I appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You've got the right idea with `trial_end`, it just needs to be a child parameter under `subscription_data`.

```
// other parameters
subscription_data: {
    trial_end=1605387163
}
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-trial_end

Comment: thanks it works. however looks like it is same trial for all the products in invoice. in other word if there are 3 product to pay and each of them has different trail days , we cannot assign them 3 different trial days. is this the case?

Comment: here is the question in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745642/prices-with-different-trial-days-in-stripe

Answer (score 5):

Brendan's answer pointed me in the right direction, for PHP the syntax to add the trial_end would be for example:

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
      .......
      Your Other parameters
      .......
      'subscription_data' => ['trial_end' => 1624110173],
        
    ]);
```

Where 1624110173 is unix timestamp for the end of the free period. See this Stripe document for general explanation of checkout process and code:

[Stripe Documents](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout)