# prices with different trial days in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a checkout session like bellow with three different product-prices, and 3 different trial days:

```
session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    customer="cus_ILmp6P6s1AfFWf",
    payment_method_types=['card'],
    line_items=[
        {
            'price': "price_1HjynjHdAaIdH7ntShQwSUAK",
            'quantity': 1,
            'tax_rates': ["txr_1Hk0zDHdAaIdH7ntg4yXtzmX", ],
        },
        {
            'price': "price_1HkaSlHdAaIdH7ntd8cbQJbG",
            'quantity': 1,
        },
        {
            'price': "price_1Hjyj5HdAaIdH7nt0YQPLd60",
            'quantity': 1,
        }, ],

    mode='subscription',
    billing_address_collection='required',
    subscription_data={'trial_period_days': 5},
    allow_promotion_codes=True,
    success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('thanks')) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('index_payment')),
)
```

however by using `subscription_data={'trial_period_days': 5}`, apparantely I have no choice but to assigne same trial period ( 5 days) to all of the items.

I was wondering if there is any way to set separate trial days for separate product/prices in checkout session. for instance what if only one of the products has trial?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a singular Subscription here with 3 different Prices. It doesn't make sense to have multiple trial periods since there's only one Subscription. Having a single Subscription with multiple billing anchors and trial periods would be a nightmare to maintain and audit later.

If you want to have separate trial periods for each Price, then you'd have to create a new Subscription for each.

Comment: could you please explain, how should I achieve this? is it doable in the current checkout session? of yes/no, how should I change the code? I appreciate any hint.

Comment: It's not possible for a single Subscription to have multiple, simultaneous trial periods. If you want that then you'd need to create 3 separate Subscriptions, which you'd either do by creating the Subscription programmatically or by creating 3 Checkout Sessions for your user to complete.